# How to select a record when linked field on same table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table1 like below:

```
Table1:

Id Question    QuestionLinkedId 
1  question1      3
2  questions2     NULL
3  question3      Null
```

How to select Question3 record if we give the question1 condition.

I have tried:

```
select t.Question 
from (
   select * 
   from Table1  
   where Question = 'Question '
) t   
where t.ID = t.QuestionLinkedId
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select Question
from Table1
where Id = (
    select QuestionLinkedId
    from Table1
    where Question = 'Question '
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   Question
 LEFT
  JOIN Question AS LinkedQuestions
    ON LinkedQuestions.Id = Quetion.QuestionLinkedId 
;
```